Add a file with pyoxidizer and use it in the script
I want to use Pyoxidizer to create a .exe for my program.
In my script I use a saved torch model (torch.load("path")).
I want to pack this file in the .exe so that it can actually use it.
I know, that I need to use importlib to access the file during runtime.
My question is, how I can add that file to the .exe.
I tried adding some stuff in the pyoxidizer.bzl but nothing worked for me.
Tried e.g. exe.add_python_resources.

what means "nothing worked"? Did you get error message? If so then show FULL error message in question (not in comment) as text (not image). Maybe you have some small mistake in code - but we can't see even minimal reproducible example, we can't see your computer, ans we can't read in your mind - so we can't help you, You have to show all details in question,.

why do you think you have to use importlib? It is needed to load Python modules not to load files with data/resourses (e.g. models). I expect that you may need "/full/path/to/model" or function which gets path to your code (e.g. BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) and it uses it to create "/full/path/to/model" (e.g. path = os.path.join(BASE, "model")). This is very common problem in other tools which creates .exe (i.e PyInstaller)
